# Présentation : futur proche ou futur simple ?

Tags: futur, futur-simple, université, futur-proche, présentation

Je me demande quel temps (futur simple ou futur proche) je dois utiliser auprès d'un comité scientifique. Par exemple :

> Mon exposé se déroule en quatre étapes. Je commencerai par un aperçu
>   de mon CV. La deuxième partie est  consacrée à mes activités
>   pédagogiques. En troisième lieu, j'aborderai mes activités de
>   recherche. Je terminerai en
>   résumant les principaux points sur lesquels s'appuie cette candidature.

Dois-je retenir le futur simple ou en changer pour le  futur proche ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le futur simple est du niveau de formalité qui convient pour un CV. Le futur proche est loin d'être aussi formel.